# setting a positional parameter in a function in bash

Tags: bash, function, shell, positional-parameter

I'm making a function to easly convert my strings to arrays as I need to.

I am somewhat running into a weird issue. I am still new to bash and this is really bugging me. Would anybody be able to shed some light onto this?

convert.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
convert2array () {
read -a $1_arr <<< $1
}

mx=$(dig +short google.com mx | cut -d' ' -f 2 | sed 's/\.$//')

convert2array "$mx"

echo ${mx_arr[@]}
```

Output:

```
bash -x convert2array.sh 
++ sed 's/\.$//'
++ cut '-d ' -f 2
++ dig +short google.com mx
+ mx='alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
alt3.aspmx.l.google.com
alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
aspmx.l.google.com
alt4.aspmx.l.google.com'
+ convert2array mx
+ read -a mx_arr
+ echo 585911
585911
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
convert2array () {
  # Bash v4+ alternative: `readarray -t` instead of `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra`
  IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra "$1" <<<"$2"
}

mx=$(dig +short google.com mx | cut -d' ' -f 2 | sed 's/\.$//')

convert2array mx_arr "$mx"

printf '%s\n' "${mx_arr[@]}"
```

---

As for what you tried:

- `$1` inside `convert2array` is not the *name* of your input variable, `$mx`, but its *value*.
  You need to pass in the name of the variable you want to declare (possibly after modifying the input name) explicitly, as a separate argument.
- `read` by default only reads the *1st* line of the input, whereas you're passing *multiple* lines.
  `-d ''` makes `read` read *all* lines, and `IFS=$'\n'` makes `read` read each line *as a whole*.
  In Bash v4+, using builtin `readarray`, `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra` can be replaced with `readarray -t`.

---

A **streamlined version of your command** would be to read the `dig ...` output lines directly into an array, using the Bash v4+ `readarray` builtin:

```
readarray -t mx_arr < <(dig +short google.com mx | cut -d' ' -f 2 | sed 's/\.$//')
```

Bash v3.x alternative:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d ''  -ra mx_arr < <(dig +short google.com mx | cut -d' ' -f 2 | sed 's/\.$//')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly store the `dig` results in the array

```
 declare -a results=( $( dig +short google.com mx | cut -d' ' -f 2 | sed 's/\.$//' ) )
 echo "${results[@]}"
```

Also, you need not use `cut` here, `sed` alone would suffice.

```
declare -a results=( $( dig +short google.com mx  | sed -E 's/^[[:digit:]]*[[:blank:]]*(.*)\.$/\1/') )
echo "${results[@]}"
aspmx.l.google.com
alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
alt4.aspmx.l.google.com
alt3.aspmx.l.google.com
```

See [[ bash arrays ]](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html#sect_10_02),[[ command subsctitution ]](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html#COMMANDSUB) and [[ positional parameters ]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#ARGLIST).

<sup>**You're warned :** The output can be but in one format. Though `( $( .. ) )` is an anti-pattern as pointed out in [**comment#1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215670/setting-a-positional-parameter-in-a-function-in-bash/41215702?noredirect=1#comment69630505_41215702) , for this case, it would suffice.</sup>

Comment: By double-quoting the command substitution you're invariably creating an array with a _single_ element containing _all lines_, which is not the intent. Without double-quoting, the output lines are invariably subject to word-splitting and globbing, and even though that happens to work in _this_ case,  `( $(...) )` is not a generally robust way to read command output into an array (unless you set `$IFS` and turn off globbing, which is not worth the effort).

Comment: @mklement0 : Thanks for the pointer. I thought about it but then forgot to take the double quotes off in a rush to post an answer :) Changed now

Comment: @mklement0 : Also, I agree to the second part of your comment

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, but I really wish you'd preface your solution with a prominent warning to that effect. I believe that `( $(...) )` is an anti-pattern that should not be promoted. It's seductively simple, but it will come back to bite you - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls?highlight=%28array%29#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29

Comment: @mklement0 : Well said, reminds me of *there are dark corners in the Bourne shell, and people use all of them- Chet Ramey*

Answer (score 1):

Just a note on what went wrong in your function:

```
convert2array () {
read -a $1_arr <<< $1
}
```

Here, you're reading in the contents of `$1`, which is the name of the variable, when you want to read the contents of the variable itself. You can use indirection here:

```
convert2array () {
  read -a $1_arr <<< ${!1}
}
```

As others have noted, there are easier ways to get your output in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the array is only a one-off, for a read-only output loop, *POSIX shell* can do it:

```
set -- `dig +short google.com mx` ; \
while [ "$2" ] ; do echo "${2%.*}" ; shift 2 ; done
```

Output:

```
alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
alt3.aspmx.l.google.com
alt4.aspmx.l.google.com
alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
aspmx.l.google.com
```

If the output needs further fussing, pipe the `echo` to whatever else it is that needs doing.

---

Note:  The above code contains a simple kludge to avoid `sed` and `cut` -- instead just output only the *even number* array members, and use [parameter expansion](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/nix/shell/gsh10-POSIXcompliantshells/) "*Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern*" to remove that '.' at the end.